# Pandas: compute the mean of a column grouped by another column

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

Say I have a dataframe like this:

```
            gender     height      weight  C
2000-01-01    male  42.849980  157.500553  1
2000-01-02    male  49.607315  177.340407  1
2000-01-03    male  56.293531  171.524640  1
2000-01-04  female  48.421077  144.251986  2
2000-01-05    male  46.556882  152.526206  2
2000-01-06  female  68.448851  168.272968  1
2000-01-07    male  70.757698  136.431469  2
2000-01-08  female  58.909500  176.499753  3
2000-01-09  female  76.435631  174.094104  3
2000-01-10    male  45.306120  177.540920  2
```

How could I compute the mean of the `height` column, grouped by column `C`? This would yield 3 different values: the mean of those heights with `C=1`, that of those with `C=2`, and so forth.

So far I tried this but to no avail:

`df['height'].mean(groupby='C')`

-> returns `TypeError: mean() got an unexpected keyword argument 'groupby'`

Comment: Are you after `df.groupby('C')['height'].mean()`?

Comment: Yes. If you want to, you can make it an answer for others to know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your syntax is incorrect, there is no `groupby` arg for `mean`, you want to [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html#pandas.DataFrame.groupby) on the col of interest and then call [`mean`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.mean.html#pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.mean) on the column of interest:

```
In [11]:
df.groupby('C')['height'].mean()

Out[11]:
C
1    54.299919
2    52.760444
3    67.672566
Name: height, dtype: float64
```